# Scraping elements inside the #shadow-root web element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get matches and their odds on [THIS PAGE](https://bluechip.io/sport?bt-path=%2Fschedule%3FscheduleSport%3Dsoccer-1)  using Python & Selenium

Below is my code:

```
inner_page = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#bt-inner-page").shadow_root
eventCard = inner_page.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//div[@data-editor-id='eventCard']"))
```

I'm getting `InvalidArgumentException`, how can I modify the code to get the team names and odds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = Chrome()

url = "https://bluechip.io/sport?bt-path=%2Fschedule%3FscheduleSport%3Dsoccer-1"
driver.get(url)

inner_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#bt-inner-page"))).shadow_root
eventCard = WebDriverWait(inner_page, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-editor-id="eventCard"]')))
print(len(eventCard))
```

output:

```
20
```

Few things to note:

1. First, we should wait for the presence of the content `bt-inner-page` to get located so that we can further look for the `shadow_root` in it.
2. Once we are inside the `shadow_root`, we need to again wait for the web element of the event cards to get loaded on the page.

As you can see above, we get all of the 20 event cards which can be further parsed accordingly as per the need.

I hope this solves your problem, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
inner_page = wait_find_css_selector(driver, "div#bt-inner-page").shadow_root
#sleep(1)
eventCard = wait_find_css_selectors(inner_page, "div[data-editor-id*='eventCard']")
```