# Can't access the latest version xpath of Google Chrome through Selenium and Chromium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chromium, shadow-root

When I access the `chrome://settings/help` site and tried to access the latest version of Google through Xpath or other channels, I couldn't access it.

I just want to get the string of the latest version of Chrome.

Are there any reasons or specific cases for not recognizing xpath?

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main"]//settings-about-page//settings-section[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"} (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199);
```

please. help.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('chrome://settings/help')
time.sleep(5)
update_check = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]//settings-about-page//settings-section[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').text
print(update_check)
```

Comment: can you add the full Traceback of the error you're getting?

Comment: @AjeetVerma    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main"]//settings-about-page//settings-section[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

Comment: the error clearly tells that the given XPATH is not correct/available on the page

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AjeetVerma Yeah.. but I don't know why.. Is there any other way to access that path?

Comment: I could tell if you can provide the URL or the HTML of the Page

Comment: @AjeetVerma put this in Chrome: `chrome://settings/help` this really does not seem to be working, I tried a couple of combinations. I do wonder if Google changed something specifically for this  `chrome://settings/help` page...

Comment: @AjeetVerma I just edited my code..

Comment: @AjeetVerma I changed my code url 'chrome://settings/help' but same problem is occured..

Comment: the reason you're unable to locate the element by XPATH is because of many  `shadow-room` which can not be found without switching to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your XPATH, I suppose you're trying to get the text of your installed Chrome version on your machine.

Since the page is highly embedded with many `shadow-root` elements that make it impossible to locate the elements that are embedded inside the `shadow-root` using the usual locator strategies such as XAPTH, CSS Selector, ID, etc.

Here's how you can do it:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('chrome://settings/help')

time.sleep(2)
update_check = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-about-page').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('settings-section')[0].querySelector('div.secondary').getInnerHTML();")
print(update_check)
```

Output:

```
Version 114.0.5735.199 (Official Build)  (64-bit)
```

References:

1. [Selenium: how to get element in shadow root of html page code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658230/selenium-how-to-get-element-in-shadow-root-of-html-page-code/76658375#76658375)
2. [How to click the button on Visa exchange rate calculator using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438279/how-to-click-the-button-on-visa-exchange-rate-calculator-using-selenium/76438642#76438642)
3. [Scraping elements inside the #shadow-root web element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76365358/scraping-elements-inside-the-shadow-root-web-element/76370202#76370202)